# Make backgroundimage clickable in a CSS grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div tag with a background image. How is it possible to make that div tag into a hyperlink on larger and smaller screens? Is it something like this?: `onclick='window.location.href="https://www.google.com"'`.

HTML:

```
<div class="sbp-item6"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.sbp-item10 {
    grid-row: 6 / 7;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url("https://placehold.it/380x250");
}
```

Comment: Would it not make more sense to just fire the click on the div instead of a background image in the div? .. or do you have a particular reason for the background image firing the click?

Comment: what do you mean with "clickable" ? What do you want to happen when you click on it ?

Comment: Hello @Lefty. Yes that would absolutely make more sense. I will reformulate my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Ari. Thank you for the comment. I just reformulated my question. I need the background image to be a hyperlink.

Comment: Why don't you use an A tag?

Comment: It should be pointed out that a `background-image` is a style, *not an element*,  and is therefore **never** clickable.

Comment: Sorrry, I don't understand what you want to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jQuery:

```
$( ".sbp-item6" ).click(function() {
     window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
});
```

I think that if you have different divs that need to point to different urls, the better solution is to set an attribute to the div to be the url. Retreive it in js. And use it to point to the url itself.

```
<div class="sbp-item6" link-to="http://www.google.com"></div>
$( ".sbp-item6" ).click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("link-to");
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

And at the end, in css:

```
.sbp-item6
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion. This is doing what I need. But I can see there is a weird problem. Lets say you click on `sbp-item6` you will get to `http://www.google.com`. If you from here click back in the browser, you will not get to the previous page. How can that be? because it is not a normal link?

Comment: You have this issue also using google as link or using something else?

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do with jquery.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $('.sbp-item6').click( function(e){
    window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I can see this is working how I would like. One thing I actually did not thing off.. How am i turning the curser into a hand when a person hover over the `sbp-item6`?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply register click handler:

```
$('.sbp-item6').on('click', (event) => {
    // your stuff here
  window.location.href="https://www.google.com"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap the div with an anchor `<a>` tag? You would have to add the `.sbp-item10` class to the `<a>` tag if you decide to do that in order to keep the same grid layout. And then if you want to remove the link at certain screen sizes you can add the following CSS property at whatever break points you want:

```
@media (max-width: 475px) {
  .sbp-item10 {
    pointer-events: 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not use block elements inside inline one in css.